# How to access a tab controller's property from each of its tabs?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I am currently passing the userId property to the tab controller, which wraps three tabs, but how do I access the userId in each of the view controllers?

I tried `[self.tabBarController userIds]` but userIds does not work and errors...

Here is the tab controller .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TrekTabController : UITabBarController {
    NSString *userProfileId, *userProfileName;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * userProfileId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * userProfileName;

@end
```

Comment: You are talking about a custom tabBarController, right?

Comment: I added the .h file of the TabController above, what do you mean by custom?

Comment: I don't understand your answer.

Comment: What do you not understand, I am confused of what you mean by custom, I simply created a tab controller file, and added properties to it

Comment: Did you add `TrekTabController.h` in the view controller implementations of the view controllers which are shown in the tabs? If so, try to add casting: `[(TrekTabController*)self.tabBarController userIds]`.

Comment: ok that worked thanks if you want to put it in the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you add `TrekTabController.h` in the view controller implementations of the view controllers which are shown in the tabs? If so, try to add casting: `[(TrekTabController*)self.tabBarController userIds]`.